# Не могу получить данные из Bundle во фрагменте. Данные передаются из activity ProductsToAdd1 в фрагмент BasketFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, android-bundle

```
public class ProductsToAdd1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_products_to_add1);

        final AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
        String[] products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.products);
        List<String> productList = Arrays.asList(products);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, productList);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_set_product1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("key", autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString());
                BasketFragment basketFragment = new BasketFragment();
                basketFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                Log.e("TextSended1",autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Код `BasketFragment`:

```
public class BasketFragment extends Fragment {
    private FloatingActionButton fabOne;
    private FloatingActionMenu floatingActionMenu;
    private DbForProducts dbForProducts;
    private ArrayList<MyProductBasket> products;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_basket, container, false);

        String myMessage = getArguments().getString("key");
        Log.e("Text_Get",myMessage);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        products = new ArrayList();
        dbForProducts = new DbForProducts(getContext());
        MyProductAdapterBasket adapter;
        adapter = new MyProductAdapterBasket(getContext(),products);
        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        products.sort(new Comparator<MyProductBasket>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MyProductBasket o1, MyProductBasket o2) {
                return o1.productName.compareTo(o2.productName);
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        fabOne = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabOne1);
        floatingActionMenu = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabfirst1);
        fabOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1;
                intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductsToAdd1.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ну, Вы даже не запускаете `BasketFragment`, как я вижу. В любом случае - необходим код `BasketFragment` и более точное описание "Не могу получить". Потому что "падает с ошибкой при попытке получения" и "null вместо данных" это несколько разные случаи, которых может быть много.

Comment: Код есть ниже и да, там null.

Comment: Я просто уже везде посмотрел, никак не пойму, почему до фрагмента данные не доходят.

Comment: А у Вас фрагмент вообще запускается? Потому что из кода Вы его НЕ запускаете!

Comment: Нет, с фрагментом всё в порядке и он запускается он просто размещён на активити, мне и не нужно туда переходить, мне просто нужно передать строку, по нажатию кнопки из активити в этот фрагмент.

Comment: Я не пойму почему Bundle не работает, почему он выдаёт null во фрагменте, хотя ключ совпадает и аргументы тоже в фрагмент переданы. Вот в чём проблема.

Comment: У Вас при нажатии на кнопку создается НОВЫЙ фрагмент. Этому НОВОМУ фрагменту Вы передаете `Bundle`. А потом его сборщик мусора уничтожает, а показываемый пользователю фрагмент - ни сном ни духом. Вам нужно используя `fragmentManager` заменить старый фрагмент новым. Почитайте [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragment-replace.php)

Comment: Возможно вы и правы, но мне кажется, здесь другая проблема, надеюсь что ваше решение верно. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну что,  у Вас получилось?)

Comment: Нет, я заново из-за этого буду переделывать весь проект, видно просто моих знаний о фрагментах ещё не достаточно. Но спасибо вам за помощь.